# How Do I Maintain User's IE Internet Options?

Tags: internet-explorer

I would like to maintain IE Internet Options for users on a terminal server without having to log in and change them manually.  Specifically, I want to be able to indicate computers to include in the Local intranet as well as setting some Custom level security settings.  Any assistance would be appreciated.  I assume there is an administrative way to get access to these, I just don't know it.  Can someone help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an Active Directory scenario you can create a GPO to set all those configuration options for your users.

If this is a stand alone server, you can configure these options by changing the options in the Local Computer Policy. To do this:

On the server (as an admin) click Start, then run and enter mmc.exe

Click File, then Add/Remove Snapin

Select Group Policy Object, click Add

Select 'Local Computer' as the realm

Click Ok, then Ok again

All set

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to using policies you can set up a user profile the way you want and copy that to the default user profile. Then any new users will inherit those settings. Policies will lock the settings in, whereas the profile method gives them the starting settings, while allowing the users to change them, giving the same results as you are currently getting.